# Sorting and colors in stacked bar chart with positive and negative values (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, plot, colors, bar-chart

I have a problem with a stacked bar chart. Please see my current code below. I have 2 problems:

1) I want to order the positive and negative data in the following way: the positive data that has most often positive values closest to the x-axis, the negative data that has most often negative values also closest to the x-axis (of course above and below the x-axis, as is done currently). The current sorting with the mean does not achieve this and I believe it also messes up the legend assignments.

2) I would like to have very different colors for the different data so that the legend is useful. I also want to assign the colors automatically so that I can use the same code structure for different plots. Please see the code below for my attempt at it, however, colors are dark and similar and therefore cannot easily be distinguished. 'Other' represent each different data, I was just tired of making up names.

Thanks a lot.

```
clc
clear

%% Datevector
datevector = {'08-Jul-2040',...
    '08-Aug-2040',...
    '08-Sep-2040',...
    '08-Oct-2040',...
    '08-Nov-2040',...
    '08-Dec-2040',...
    '08-Jan-2041',...
    '08-Feb-2041',...
    '08-Mar-2041',...
    '08-Apr-2041',...
    '08-May-2041',...
    '08-Jun-2041',...
    '08-Jul-2041',...
    '08-Aug-2041',...
    '08-Sep-2041',...
    '08-Oct-2041',...
    '08-Nov-2041',...
    '08-Dec-2041',...
    '08-Jan-2042',...
    '08-Feb-2042',...
    '08-Mar-2042',...
    '08-Apr-2042',...
    '08-May-2042',...
    '08-Jun-2042',...
    '08-Jul-2042',...
    '08-Aug-2042',...
    '08-Sep-2042'};

%% Cash flows
data{1} = -5*rand(27,1);
data{2} = -3*rand(27,1);
data{3} = -5*rand(27,1);
data{4} = 4*rand(27,1);
data{5} = 2*rand(27,1);
data{6} = 3*rand(27,1);
data{7} = 2*rand(27,1);
data{8} = 1*rand(27,1);
data{9} = 5*rand(27,1);
data{10} = 3*rand(27,1);
data{11} = 4*rand(27,1);
data{12} = 1*rand(27,1);
data{13} = 5*rand(27,1);
data{14} = 3*rand(27,1);
data{15} = 4*rand(27,1);
data{16} = 1*rand(27,1);
data{17} = 5*rand(27,1);
data{18} = 3*rand(27,1);
data{19} = 4*rand(27,1);
data{20} = 1*rand(27,1);
data{21} = 5*rand(27,1);
data{22} = 3*rand(27,1);
data{23} = 4*rand(27,1);

labels = {'revenueFixed';...
'revenueMarket';...
'fullService';...
'partService';...
'lease';...
'techMgmt';...
'comMgmt';...
'guarantee';...
'decommission';...
'repowering';...
'taxAudit';...
'other';...
'other';...
'other';...
'other';...
'other';...
'other';...
'other';...
'other';...
'other';...
'other';...
'other';...
'other'};

colors = zeros(size(labels,1),3);
colors(1:7,:) = [1 1 0;...
1 0 1;...
0 1 1;...
1 0 0;...
0 1 0;...
0 0 1;...
1 1 1];

noAdditionalColors = size(labels,1)-7;
rounds = ceil(noAdditionalColors/7);
multiplier = 0.5.^(1:rounds);

for noRounds = 1:rounds-1
    for noColor = noRounds*7+1 : (noRounds+1)*7
        colors(noColor,:) = multiplier(noRounds) .* colors(noColor-noRounds*7,:);
    end
end

for noRounds = rounds
    for noColor = rounds*7+1 : rounds*7 + rem(noAdditionalColors,7)
        colors(noColor,:) = multiplier(noRounds) .* colors(noColor-noRounds*7,:);
    end
end

xData = datenum(datevector,'dd-mmm-yyyy');
for i = 1:numel(data)
    dataNeg{i} = data{i};
    dataNeg{i}(data{i}>0) = 0;
    dataPos{i} = data{i};
    dataPos{i}(data{i}<0) = 0;
    mdata(i) = mean(data{i});
end
[~,posOrder] = sort(mdata,'ascend');
[~,negOrder] = sort(mdata,'descend');
yDataPos = [dataPos{posOrder}];
yDataNeg = [dataNeg{negOrder}];
hold on;
bNeg = bar(xData,yDataNeg,'stack');
bPos = bar(xData,yDataPos,'stack');
datetick('x','yyyy','keeplimits');
for i= 1:numel(data)
    set(bNeg(i),'FaceColor',colors(negOrder(i),:))
    set(bPos(i),'FaceColor',colors(posOrder(i),:))
end
legend(labels{:});
hold off;
```

Comment: The process of creating different colors can be simplified by using a builtin colormap but you're requiring 23 different colors here. That's way too many. Like it or not, some of them will definitely look similar to the eyes; and you'll always be having a problem distinguishing them. I suggest dividing your bar graph to like 2 or 3 separate graphs where you may visualise them easily

Comment: Yeah I know but dividing into sub-plots is unfortunately not an option. So I'd like to just make the colors as different as possible and see how it looks. If you have suggestions for 1) or 2), go for it.